# Deserializing missing type with protobuf.net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have an application with plugin architecture. The plugins have their own data containers, which all inherit from the base interface IPluginDataStorage. The DataStorage object, which is serialized to preserve state, contains a list of these subclasses along with other data. The DynamicType flag is set to true, as it's not known until run time which plugins are in use.

```
[Serializable]
[ProtoContract]
public class DataStorage
{
    [ProtoMember(200, DynamicType = true)]
    public List<IPluginDataContainer> PluginDataStorage { get; set; }
```

When serializing this setup works okay, but I'm having problems deserializing the list reliably. If I try to deserialize the object without having access to all those plugins that were used when it was serialized, I, naturally, get an exception about a missing type.

> Unable to resolve type: NOSMemoryConsumptionPlugin.NOSMemoryConsumptionData, NOSMemoryConsumptionPlugin, Version=1.2.0.17249, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null (you can use the TypeModel.DynamicTypeFormatting event to provide a custom mapping)

The exception gives a hint that I could provide the format through the event, but I don't see how that could be helpful as the problem is that I don't have that type available. What I'd like to do in these cases is to completely ignore deserializing that object. The list item could even default to a dummy instance of the base class in these cases. But how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

That (choosing to skip or default) is a fascinating use-case that I don't think I have considered fully; however, you can *probably* do this yourself, via:

```
public class NilContainer : IPluginDataContainer {}
```

and then subscribe to the  `DynamicTypeFormatting` event; if you don't recognise the type, supply `typeof(NilContainer)`.

i.e.

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.DynamicTypeFormatting += (sender, args) =>
{
    Type type;
    if(!yourTypeMap.TryGetValue(args.FormattedName, out type))
    {
        type = typeof (NilContainer);
    }
    args.Type = type;
};
```

(completely untested)

Comment: Sadly it does not seem to work. Providing the type gives a InvalidOperationException with: "Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred: MemoryAnalyzer.NilContainer"